# C - What does ~ mean

Tags: c, linux, visual-c++, gcc

Today I am understanding the header files of Linux Cross Platform while reading on [here written code on specific lin](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/acpi/platform/acenv.h#L300)

```
#define _bnd(X, bnd)            (((sizeof (X)) + (bnd)) & (~(bnd)))
```

I want to know what does (~) sign do. I have not found any documentation regarding this character anywhere.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=C+tilde

Answer (score 2):

The `~` operator is the bitwise not operator.
This will make all the binary ones in a number zero and all the zeros will become ones.

You can consider the `~` operator as a way of inverting a binary number. For example, when you are using flags, the `~` operator will turn off all flags that were previously on and vice versa.

Mathematically, the `~` operator is one less than the twos-complement of a number.

So, using a concrete example:

```
Let a = 1010 (binary)
Then ~a = 0101 (binary)
```